# Работа с ботом Discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Хочу сделать так, чтобы когда бот заходил на дискорд сервер, то создавался специальный канал для него. Не знаю как это можно сделать :(
Пробовал:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready(ctx):
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel("text")
```

Не работает. Еще хотелось бы узнать, как заставить бота писать только в этот канал. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Данный код не работает, потому что у события `on_ready` нету аргумента `ctx`. И вообще, он так будет при каждом запуске создавать канал, если вы укажете айди сервера. А работать будет данный код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    global cmds_channel #объявление переменной с созданием текстового канала глобальной
    cmds_channel = await guild.create_text_channel('комманды-боту')#ну или любой другое имя канала
```

Также, попробую ответить на второй вопрос. Я не очень уверен, что это заработает, но попробуйте и напишите, если заработает)

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == cmds_channel.id:#сравнение айди канала сообщения и айди канала для работы с ботом
        await bot.process_commands(message)#разрешение работы комманд
    else:
        return#если же не совпадает, ничего не делать
```